# Black Ops Care Packages - Killstreak Challenges

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops, achievements

If I get a care package, which contains a spy plane, does using that spy plane count towards my spy plane killstreak challenges?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It does, all killstreak rewards that came from the care packages count to your killstreak challenges. In fact, I had a Chopper Gunner from a care package which was added to my Chopper Gunner killstreak count. Which proves killstreak rewards earned from care packages definitely count towards to the killstreak challenges.

Comment: sweet, cheers youbook