# MW3 Care Packages - Killstreak Challenges

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I previously asked this question:

[Black Ops Care Packages - Killstreak Challenges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16268/black-ops-care-packages-killstreak-challenges)

It's asking whether or not killstreak rewards which are given when you open a care package killstreak contribute to challenges.

Do they contribute in Modern Warfare 3 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do.  However, I believe it is only towards the "Prestige" challenges, and not the ones under the Assault Strike Package challenge menu.

Even though I never take the Assault strike package, I have several levels of multiple killstreak rewards "Prestige" challenges completed because of care packages I picked up that belonged to other players.

Comment: I believe they do count towards the regular assault strike package challenges, as I have gotten several challenges complete for killstreaks I never select.

Comment: @SSumner, It's possible.  I may not have seen any care packages this prestige, although I'm level 70 now, so I'd assume I'd have grabbed a few here or there along the way.